# view sqlite database in android studio

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have created a database named `"company"` using android studio. When I want to view the database I created, I can't find it.

I follow the step below

```
Open DDMS via Tools > Android > Android Device Monitor
```

and see my project name on the left.

However, when I go to File Explorer,go to /data/data/com.example.project.project, I didn't see the database created which should under database package. There only have two folder there, one is `cache` and another is `code_cache.` What steps I have missed out? Hope someone can help me to figuring out the problem. Thanks

**MyDataBaseHelper.java**

```
package com.example.project.project.database;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;


public class MyDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME="Company.db";
    public final static String TABLE_NAME="TimeSheet";
    public static final String ID="id";
    public static final String Name="name";
    public static final String Weather="weather";
   // public static final String DATABASE_CREATE_TIME_SHEET="create table"+TABLE_NAME+"(+ Name+"TEXT,"+ Weather+"TEXT)";
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        db.execSQL("create table "+TABLE_NAME+"(name text,weather text)");
    }

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion,int newVersion)
    {
        Log.w(MyDatabaseHelper.class.getName(),"Upgrading database from version"+oldVersion+"to"+newVersion+",which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("Drop TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public MyDatabaseHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME,null,1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Running app on Emulator or Real Device?

Comment: running on emulator..

Comment: Did you try changing the column type("text") to upper case("TEXT")?

Comment: Creating object of  `MyDatabaseHelper` from Activity? if not then add `new MyDatabaseHelper(this)` in onCreate of Activity

Comment: database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase(); try this

Comment: I hope you tried writing or reading from database using getWritableDatabase()/getReadableDatabase().

Comment: Thanks..I really miss out writing or reading the statement from database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missed out this

```
database=dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

Answer (score 1):

Step 1] Download SQLite Manager in Mozilla Fire Fox.

Step 2] Open Android Device Monitor.

Step 3] Find your Database .

Step 4] Pull your database file to desktop or anywhere.

step 5] Start SQlite Manager from Mozilla.

step 6] Import your database in SQLite Manager.

In SQLite Manager you can see your database ,database table ,records,etc.