# SQLite Database not in Android Device Manager

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite

I have been following tutorials for finding SQLite database in Android Studio.

Tools > Android > Android Device Manager > File Explorer

The data folder will not open so I can go to the path data/data/myproject/database name.

I am using the emulator.

[image]

Comment: Check your code, did you wrote `getReadableDatabase()` ?

Comment: Are you doing this on a real device or the emulator? A real device needs to be rooted to see this folder.

Comment: @JohnJoe I am able to save information to the database and tables. I am able to pull the information back out. I just wanted to see what my database and tables look like. Where would I put getReadableDatabase(). I have it in my code when I am getting data out of the table.

Comment: @Marc it is emulator

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32557370/view-sqlite-database-in-android-studio

Comment: @JohnJoe I cannot comment on that page but would you happen to know where I need to add the database=dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Your doing the right thing but it only work with emulator and devices running API 23 and lower. 
Try rebuilding the project at a lower API.